# Assigning the result of an Ajax call to a button in a Bootstrap Modal popup form

Tags: jquery

I am trying to assign the result of an Ajax call to a button in a modal popup form that loads after the Ajax response. I have read a number of posts but none seem to match what I am trying to do.

Ajax result:

```
var result = JSON.stringify(data);
result = JSON.parse(result);

var recordid = result[0];
$('#EditRecordID').val(result[0]);
```

Form button:

```
<button type="button" data="EditRecordID" id="EditRecordID" class="btn btn-warning-edit btn-xs" >View</button>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Your JS code will work fine (although the `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` is entirely redundant and can be removed). However the bigger issue is what you expect the `value` of the button to do after you've added it.

Comment: I'm not sure that the form element button has a value attribut. But it is also possible that I'm wrong.

Comment: It's possible in theory. Button does not have `.val()`, also make sure you assign it in callback, not in "sync way"

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Hi, I did have a typo in my code which has now been corrected and now the button is assigned the expected value. I now want to use the value assign to the button in a function that uses the value in a POST variable to another Ajax call.

Comment: This is the result of the ajax response. <button type="button" data="EditRecordID" id="EditRecordID" class="btn btn-warning-edit btn-xs" value="50639">View</button>

Comment: @Justinas @reporter buttons do indeed have a `value`, so `val()` will work, it's just not commonly used: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: @DCJones ok, so in your click handler on the button you can just use `$(this).val()` to get the value you set on the button. You can include that value in the data you send via AJAX

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Hi, I have learned another lesson. Many thanks Rory. If you change this as an answer I can mark it as done and working.

Comment: I think you can't use `val()` for the inner html tag. simple way is to use `html()` instead